# Does Migration for F1 to F2 server makes Datastore operations faster

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a google appengine application for Python 2.5. I know that migration from F1 to F2 has impact on computations and processing, but it also improves datastore read/write operations?

Comment: You might want to switch to 2.7 first before messing arround with F1 and F2.. http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2013/03/python-25-thanks-for-good-times.html

Comment: Even after switching to python 2.7, does migration from F1 to F2 will improve datastore read/write operations?

Comment: I don't have any empirical evidence to share, but if you think about it I don't believe front end performance will have any impact on read/write performance where the measured time is for the round trip of the RPC to the backend services.  It would make a difference to encoding/decoding the protobufs on the front end and anything any other work you do locally.

Answer (score 2):

No.

GAE database does not run on frontend instances, it's a separate service. So increasing memory/processor on frontend instance will do nothing for speed of DB operations.

Proper db architecture will have the biggest impact on DB speed, but this is quite a broad topic. Just some generic hints:

1. Reorganize entities so that for the most oft used entities you use get instead of query.
2. Use memcache to cache entities that you often get.
3. If doing multiple independent operations, use async and do them in parallel.
4. If you get/put multiple entities, use bulk operations.

Comment: Correct answer.

Just a small note - strictly speaking it "will" improve datastore operations as serializing/deserializing is made on "client" side of RPC call so having F2 theoretically mean it would be done faster. But for such a small margin that it does not worth thinking about it.